# Creating multiple themes (css files) with Foundation, Grunt, Sass

Tags: sass, gruntjs, zurb-foundation

I would like to create a number of different themes for foundation for my Foundation web app (basically switch color schemes for different customers). I am still very new to Sass, libsass and grunt.

Basically what I want is something like: have two different _settings.scss files

_settingsA.css

```
$primary_color: #cc3333;
...
```

_settingsB.css

```
$primary_color: #3333cc;
...
```

And with those two files generate foundationA.css and foundationB.css.
I am currently using Foundation with Sass/Grunt.

Comment: I know it's simple but I'm still trying to figure out how grunt generates the .css file and don't have a clue. I just asked because here there's always people willing to help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just found that the solution is editing Gruntfile.js and adding files to the "sass" task:

```
sass: {
      options: {
        includePaths: ['bower_components/foundation/scss']
      },
      dist: {
        options: {
          outputStyle: 'compressed'
        },
        files: {
          'css/app.css': 'scss/app.scss',
          'css/app2.css': 'scss/app2.scss',
          'css/app3.css': 'scss/app3.scss'
        }
      }
    }
```